# Show that a polynomial $f(x)$ over a field $k$ is irreducible if the polynomial $f(x+1)$ is irreducible

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I was thinking of using contradiction by assuming that that $f(x)$ is reducible but I really don't know how to continue from that idea.

Comment: Hint: can you show that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ if and only if $f(x+1)=g(x+1)h(x+1)$?

Comment: $g(x)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ if and only if $g(x+1)$ is a factor of $f(x+1)$...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f(x)$ is reducible. Then:

$\exists \ h(x), \ g(x) \in \mathbb K[x]$ such that $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$.

Then: $f(x + 1) = g(x+1)h(x+1)$, and so reducible. A contradiction.

Comment: Argument is missing an important point, e.g. why can't $\,g(x+1)\,$ be constant?

Comment: Because $g(x)$ isn't.

Comment: You need to *explicitly* mention that, else the proof is incorrect.

Comment: I wouldn't even call it an argument, it was just a hint. Details are left to the OP.

Comment: If it is a hint, then you should say that, and mention that some details are left to the reader.

Comment: By the way, the proof is missing, and not "incorrect". Moreover, we are not doing tests here, so it isn't a great deal not to mention one thing or a two.

Answer (score -1):

Let's prove the contrapositive:  That if $f(x)$ is reducible then $g(x) \equiv f(x+1)$ is also reducible.  That is logically equivalent to the statement to be proven.

Since $f(x)$ is reducible there exists some $x_0\in K:f(x_0)=0$.  Then since $1 \in K$ and $K$ is a field, $y\equiv x_0-1 \in K$.  And 
$$
g(y) = f((x_0-1)+1) = f(x_0) = 0
$$ so $g(x)$ is reducible.

**EDITED** in response to Bill's comment:

This "proof" is invalid.  Yes, if $f(x)$ has a zero then $g(x)$ is irreducible.  But we don't know that $f(x)$ has a zero; all we know is that it is irreducible.  So "step 1.5" in the above proof is hogwash.  Sorry.

Comment: Reducible polynomials need not have roots, e.g. $\,(x^2+1)^2 \in\Bbb R[x].\ $

Comment: @Bill Dubuque:  You are right, I goofed.  Thanks for pointing it out.